# Error creating a Taproot descriptor with a single key as script path

Tags: output-script-descriptors, p2tr

I need to implement 1 of 2 multisig with P2TR.

My friend's Bitcoin public key is `0374d5f29bc6c15066437856c512f7f9e5a14a1eb93cab2776d33b27b4103c62d8`.
My own Bitcoin public key is `035d107216d89a540edacba2bc6719f3a9c6eac538bebac8b305e8cd42c3e466ae`/

I will use my public key as the Key Path and my friend's as script path.

Can anybody tell me how to create a P2TR descriptor?

I got following errors:

```
./bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcwallet=w_p2tr getdescriptorinfo "tr([0d378869/44'/1'/0'/0/1]035d107216d89a540edacba2bc6719f3a9c6eac538bebac8b305e8cd42c3e466ae, [(0xC0, [0374d5f29bc6c15066437856c512f7f9e5a14a1eb93cab2776d33b27b4103c62d8, OP_CHECKSIG])]"
error code: -5
error message:
'tr([0d378869/44'/1'/0'/0/1]035d107216d89a540edacba2bc6719f3a9c6eac538bebac8b305e8cd42c3e466ae, [(0xC0, [0374d5f29bc6c15066437856c512f7f9e5a14a1eb93cab2776d33b27b4103c62d8, OP_CHECKSIG])]' is not a valid descriptor function
```

AND:

```
./bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcwallet=w_p2tr getdescriptorinfo "tr([0d378869/44'/1'/0'/0/0]035d107216d89a540edacba2bc6719f3a9c6eac538bebac8b305e8cd42c3e466ae, { pk(0374d5f29bc6c15066437856c512f7f9e5a14a1eb93cab2776d33b27b4103c62d8) })"
error code: -5
error message:
' { pk(0374d5f29bc6c15066437856c512f7f9e5a14a1eb93cab2776d33b27b4103c62d8) }' is not a valid descriptor function
```

BUT I got the descriptor right for key base only:

```
./bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcwallet=w_p2tr getdescriptorinfo "tr([0d378869/44'/1'/0'/0/0]035d107216d89a540edacba2bc6719f3a9c6eac538bebac8b305e8cd42c3e466ae)"
{
  "descriptor": "tr([0d378869/44'/1'/0'/0/0]035d107216d89a540edacba2bc6719f3a9c6eac538bebac8b305e8cd42c3e466ae)#wfd6rw0p",
  "checksum": "wfd6rw0p",
  "isrange": false,
  "issolvable": true,
  "hasprivatekeys": false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is a single leaf in the descriptor you should not use brackets for the script path:

```
tr([0d378869/44'/1'/0'/0/0]035d107216d89a540edacba2bc6719f3a9c6eac538bebac8b305e8cd42c3e466ae,pk(0374d5f29bc6c15066437856c512f7f9e5a14a1eb93cab2776d33b27b4103c62d8))
```